# QWebEngine pdf рендер таблиц

Tags: html, c++, qt, qwebengine

Для формирования отчетов использую QWebEnginePage, из которого можно производить печать в PDF, все очень удобно, но присутствует проблема с печатью таблиц.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На изображение слева - это html страница с таблицей, справа - сохраненный PDF с этой страницы, как видим, строка таблицы разрывается на две страница PDF, что не очень красиво, как этого можно избежать?
Что интересно, если эту же страницу открыть в браузере Google chrome и воспользоваться инструментом печати оттуда, то он предлагает правильные "разрывы"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или возможно, нужно отказаться от таблиц в пользу других структур?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением проблемы оказалось - обновиться до Qt 5.9, больше ничего не менял, таблицы стали печататься нормально.